# нужно ли оптимизировать запрос к базе в цикле?

Tags: laravel

```
$roles = []// данные приходят от пользователя какие роли они выберет

        foreach ($roles as $role){
            $roleTemp = Role::where('slug', $role)->first();
            $registeredEmployee->roles()->attach($roleTemp->id);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получить коллекцию с идентификаторами ролей, используя методы [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#additional-where-clauses) и [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values):

```php
$rolesTempIds = Role::whereIn('slug', $roles)->pluck('id');
$registeredEmployee->roles()->attach($rolesTempIds);
```

Comment: спасибо, а то я видел что этот меnод используется только для id array оказывается для любого столбца

Answer (score 0):

Очень плохая идея делать запросы к БД в цикле, даже если вам надо выбрать только одну запись

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Александр, я с вами согласен что надо было просто написать как комментарий, но и логика в том, что я ответил как ответил есть: иногда можно правильным ответом засчитать тот, где не содержится ответа, но есть рекомендация как делать точно не стоит. Возможно, автор вопроса принял бы это к сведению и рассмотрел другие варианты решения